# Point of collision between Shapes

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8, shapes

I have a problem in with colissions in JavaFX.

First, I detect a collision between a line and a circle using the follow code:

```
if(line.getBoundsInParent().intersects(circle.getBoundsInParent())){  
 System.out.println("Collision!");  
}
```

After this, I need catch the coordinate of collision, like the below figure:

[image: Figure]

How can I catch this coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

Since Line and Circle are both Shapes, you can use the static method `intersect` in Shape to find their intersection:

```
Shape collisionArea = Shape.intersect(line, circle)
```

That `collisionArea` is a Node as well, so you can use its `boundsInParent` to find out where to collision took place. Or you could use `localToScene` or `localToScreen` to transform local coordinates to scene or screen coordinates if you prefer those.